# addEventListener for two diffrent arrays - forEach -code optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, html

I'm just starting to learn javascript. And I have a problem to find an improvement to this code.

Is it possible to include two different arrays from 'document.querySelectorAll' in one function forEach or other way to optimize tbelow code? I know how to do it with one, but, I have no idea how to combine buttons and sections that the first element (button[0]) from one array fefers to the first (section[0]) of the other array?. How I could make this code better, that would be shorter amd more flexible?

Thank you for help!

```
function scrollSections(element) {
  window.scrollTo({
    'behavior': 'smooth',
    'left': 0,
    'top': element.offsetTop
  });
}

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.js-btn');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.js-section');

btns[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollSections(sections[0]);
});

btns[1].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollSections(sections[1]);
});

btns[2].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollSections(sections[2]);
});

btns[3].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollSections(sections[3]);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a `forEach` loop like so:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.js-btn');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.js-section');
btns.forEach((btn, index) => btn.addEventListener("click", () => scrollSections(sections[index])));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.js-btn');

btns.forEach( (btn, index) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    scrollSections(sections[index]);
  });
});
```

> NodeList objects are collections of nodes, usually returned by properties such as Node.childNodes and methods such as document.querySelectorAll().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Methods

But as can I see, you try to do smooth scrolling through the page, and I recommend made it by another way. Please have a look this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0ovm2l67w)

This better way because you don't rely to element position in sections array, so has less points of fail.

NOTE: I used data attribute because codesandbox broke anchor urls, you can switch them to `event.target.href`

Comment: Good to know :)  thanks for showing another way for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding a `forEach`and using it's index

```js
function scrollSections(element) {
  window.scrollTo({
    'behavior': 'smooth',
    'left': 0,
    'top': element.offsetTop
  });
}

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.js-btn');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.js-section');



btns.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    scrollSections(index)
  })

})
```